# NSURLSessionResponseBecomeDownload and NSURLSessionDownloadTask delegate issue

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, ios9.1

In my project, I start a `NSURLSessionDataTask` to check the header of a request, and if they're right, I turn the request into a download or I just discard it:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
{
        if (XYZ) {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseCancel);
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseBecomeDownload);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am incurring into a problem: once the session is turned into `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, sometimes nothing happens and `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location` isn't called at all, and `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error` either.

What's happening here? Does it make sense?!

**––– EDIT –––**

Apparently this solves the problem?

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didBecomeDownloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
{
    // Resume the Download Task manually because apparently iOS does not do it automatically?!
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch your edit was really helpful!

Comment: Nice catch, both the data and download tasks are passed with NSURLSessionTaskStateSuspended as state